# Swift make NSDate from string not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, timezone, nsdate

I'm trying to convert a date string into a NSDate. I have this input date string `2014-10-09 17:57` and this timezone `+4` or `Asia/Dubai` and for some reason, i get this NSDate after i execute the code below `2014-10-09 13:57:00 +0000`.

```
let dateString = "2014-10-09 17:57"
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "Asia/Dubai")
println("\(formatter.dateFromString(dateString))")
```

I want to get a date like this `2014-10-09 17:57 +0400`. What am i doing wrong? Can you help me figure it out? I need the date to make some calculations between this one and another one which is correctly formatted with timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to breakup compound statements. The result of the formatter is a date, seconds since the reference date (GMT), it has no concept of a format or timezone.

The `println()` displays the date based ion the default formatting of there description method.

If you want it display in a particular way use a date formatter to create the desired string representation.

Example:

```
let dateString = "2014-10-09 17:57"
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "Asia/Dubai")
let date = formatter.dateFromString(dateString)
println("date: \(date!)") // date: 2014-10-09 13:57:00 +0000

formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm Z"
let formattedDateString = formatter.stringFromDate(date!)
println("formattedDateString: \(formattedDateString)") // formattedDateString: 2014-10-09 17:57 +0400
```

Comment: Thanks for the comm. I don't want to display it. `println` is just for debug purposes. I need to make some calculations with this date and another one. The second one is correctly formatted (with timezone and everything).

Comment: The date is the number of seconds from the first instant of 1 January 2001, GMT. It has no timezone and no formatting and comparisons work across timezones. The description method is confusing you, it is just the way Apple decided to display the time, it has nothing to do with the actual time.

Comment: In fact i want to check if the current time in Dubai is greater than the one in the string `2014-10-09 17:57`

Comment: Yes, it will compare the times in GMT (UTC). So if at the same instance you can another person in another timezone both create `NSDate` and compare them they will have the same time,

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I have just one more question. From what i understood, to create a NSDate with timezone i have to do the following: 1. Create date formatter. 2. Set timezone. 3. Set dateFormat. 4. Call `dateFromString`. But what if i don't have the string date and i want to use the current time?

Comment: For the current time and timezone: `let date = NSDate()`