# NSDateformatter does not provide correct date swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

When I am using NSDateformatter to get date from string it returns wrong value.I dont know what must be reason.Please help me to resolve.
Thanks in advance.

```
Input String:-

    newDate "06:11"
    end time "07:00"
    start time "05:00"

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    let date:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)!
    println(date)

Output Date:- 
current date 2000-01-01 00:41:00 +0000
end date 2000-01-01 01:30:00 +0000
start date 1999-12-31 23:30:00 +0000
```

Comment: Look I know nothing about swift, but it looks like you are putting in a time, without a reference to a date, and the system is (perhaps) defaulting to the epoch date plus your time - all expressed in UTC rather than your time zone?

Comment: Might be issue is your are println of NSDate Object try to println string of NSDate.

Comment: @NitinGohel If i want to know what would be date after conversion then how i would be able to know that?

Comment: check that following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289903/swift-make-nsdate-from-string-not-working-as-expected

Comment: @NitinGohel Yes it worked i need to change date to string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing

```
println(date)
```

You are printing the description of the date, which is equal to -

```
println(date.description())
```

And it always prints the time in UTC (GMT)
So if you are in UTC+5:30, it will display time that is before 5:30 hours than your entered time. If you want to print date in your timezone, use a NSDateFormatter again. To see date of other time zone, set NSDateFormatter timeZone.

Hope this explains.

Comment: You mean I should again convert date to string then print value?

Comment: Yes, because printing the date directly, prints its description, which apple had kept a standard way of presenting in UTC format

Comment: No intentions of stealin :P Just gave a fast answer to help him.

Comment: just kidding bro enjoy.